# How to get three horizontal images to display next to each other

Tags: html, css, image, layout

I've got three images that need to be displayed horizontally with no gaps between them and a link on top of each one they also need to be scalable to the window size. Currently there are gaps between them.

Here is all of the relevant code I've got so far:

```css
.callout-container {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 480px;
  right: 0px;
}

.callout {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  Width: 33.3%;
}

.button-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 160px;
  right: 1420px;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(224, 99, 38);
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  font-family: Futura;
  font-size: 20pt;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.button-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 160px;
  right: 825px;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(224, 99, 38);
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  font-family: Futura;
  opacity: 0.9;
  font-size: 20pt;
}

.button-3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 160px;
  right: 220px;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(224, 99, 38);
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  font-family: Futura;
  opacity: 0.9;
  font-size: 20pt;
}
```

```html
<div class="callout-container">
  <div>
    <div class="callout-one callout">
      <img src="callout_1.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="callout-two callout">
      <img src="callout_2.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="callout-three callout">
      <img src="callout_3.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <a href="" class="button-1" style="text-decoration:none;">
                Property Owner?
            </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="" class="button-2" style="text-decoration:none;">
                City Visitor?
            </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="" class="button-3" style="text-decoration:none;"> 
                Teacher?
            </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit: also here is a screenshot of how it is currently displayed.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXOUQ.jpg)

Comment: Instead of position,try display:inline-block; for those images.

Comment: Your code and description don't to seem to line up. Could please improve your code and question. Make sure your code provides a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

if I understand well, you want the links to be aligned with the images?

I create a jsFiddle to test.
https://jsfiddle.net/mp9007/aL27fxm3/

I think i'm close to want you want:

```
<div class="callout-container">
   <div>
      <div class="callout-one callout">
          <a href="" class="button-1" style="text-decoration:none;"> Property Owner?</a>
      <!-- image -->
      </div>
   <div class="callout-two callout">
      <a href="" class="button-2" style="text-decoration:none;"> City visitor?</a>
      <!-- image -->
   </div>
   <div class="callout-three callout">
       <a href="" class="button-3" style="text-decoration:none;"> Teacher?</a>
      <!-- image -->
    </div>
 </div>
```

And then remove the absolute/right alignement from the css button class

```
.button-3{
   position: absolute;
   top: 160px;
   //right: 220px;
   color: white;
   background-color: rgb(224, 99, 38);
   padding: 10px;
   padding-left: 100px;
   padding-right: 100px;
   font-family: Futura;
   opacity: 0.9;
   font-size: 20pt;
}
```